# Magento Page Formatting

Tags: html, magento

I am trying to style a sales page on Magento. Here is the page: http://petpresto.com.au/why-choose-us/

I go to CMS > Pages and create a page that looks great. It is all centered and vertically aligned nicely. But then when I publish the page and look at it live on the site it looks horrible. What am I doing wrong?

Specifics I need help with:

1. Vertically align the text in cells tables
2. Center align the page
3. Make the background of the page white
4. Text and images responsive (if possible?)
5. On chrome the top three images are shrunk down in size, but not on firefox or explorer. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

I'm going crazy trying to get this to look half decent, please help!

SCREENSHOT: Here is a screenshot form the editor showing what it should look like. It shows the first few tables/cells, the rest of the page looks similar as you scroll down.

[image]

Full copy of code pasted below.

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: xx-large;">Why Choose Us?</span></strong></p>
<p><img style="width: 100%; height: 15px;" src="http://www.petpresto.com.au/images/divider_line.png" alt="" /></p>
<table style="width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img title="Free Express Shipping" src="http://petpresto.com.au/images/free-delivery256.jpg" alt="Free Express Shipping" width="256" height="256" /></td>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-large;">FREE Express Shipping</span></strong></p>
<p>You get FREE&nbsp;<strong>Express Delivery</strong>&nbsp;with Australia Post.</p>
<p>Anything you order by 4pm (AEST) will be shipped the same day. Tracking number will be provided so you can follow the parcel on the Australia Post website.</p>
<p>Items under 1kg and in metro areas will arrive the next business day, others a maximum of three days.&nbsp;Super fast!</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><img style="width: 100%; height: 15px;" src="http://www.petpresto.com.au/images/divider_line.png" alt="" /></p>
<table style="width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img title="Money Back Guarantee" src="http://petpresto.com.au/images/money-back-guarantee256.png" alt="Money Back Guarantee" width="256" height="239" /></td>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-large;">Money Back Guarantee</span></strong></p>
<p>You're covered by our famous FULL 100% No Questions Asked Money Back Guarantee!</p>
<p>If you want your money back just return the product within 28 days and we'll give you a<strong> full refund, no questions asked.</strong> Additional shipping is the buyers responsibility.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><img style="width: 100%; height: 15px;" src="http://www.petpresto.com.au/images/divider_line.png" alt="" /></p>
<table style="width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img title="Two Year Warranty" src="http://petpresto.com.au/images/2-year-warranty256.png" alt="Two Year Warranty" width="256" height="195" /></td>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-large;">Two Year Warranty</span></strong></p>
<p>You get a&nbsp;2 Year Warranty&nbsp;covering any defects.</p>
<p>We go to great lengths to ensure our products outlast the competition in every way - but in the rare case that something does go wrong just contact us for a&nbsp;<strong>free replacement or refund</strong>.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><img style="width: 100%; height: 15px;" src="http://www.petpresto.com.au/images/divider_line.png" alt="" /></p>
<table style="width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img title="Warehouse Pricing" src="http://petpresto.com.au/images/warehouse256.png" alt="Warehouse Pricing" width="256" height="256" /></td>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-large;">Discount Warehouse Price</span></strong></p>
<p>Your products are<strong> shipped&nbsp;direct from our Sydney warehouse.</strong></p>
<p>This cuts out any middle man and reduces business expenses.</p>
<p>All of those savings are then passed on to you. So you get the lowest possible price!</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><img style="width: 100%; height: 15px;" src="http://www.petpresto.com.au/images/divider_line.png" alt="" /></p>
<table style="width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img title="Australian Business" src="http://petpresto.com.au/images/Australia-Flag256.png" alt="Australian Business" width="256" height="256" /></td>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-large;">Australian Business</span></strong></p>
<p>We are&nbsp;100% Australian owned and operated.</p>
<p>Buying Australian gives you peace of mind. We are just around the corner if you need any help.</p>
<p>Plus you get that warm fuzzy feeling for supporting a genuine Ozzie business.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p><img style="width: 100%; height: 15px;" src="http://www.petpresto.com.au/images/divider_line.png" alt="" /></p>
<table style="width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><img title="All Cards Welcome" src="http://petpresto.com.au/images/visa-mastercard256.png" alt="All Cards Welcome" width="256" height="281" /></td>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="font-size: x-large;">Safe and Secure Payment</span></strong></p>
<p>Your payment is safley and securley processed through our PCI-DSS certified payment processor.</p>
<p>We accept all major cards including Visa, Mastercard, American Express, Dinners Club, and more.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post a print of how it should look like pls?

Comment: Hello, screenshot uploaded to original question now

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below and see if it fits your needs.

```
.std table {
    float:none; 
    margin: auto;
 }

.std img {
    height:138px;
    width:138px;
    /* max-width: 100%; remove this */
}
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9RvUC/)**

Now there is one thing i don't quite understand... Do you want the background color to be white or not? Cause if you go with the `#f7f7f6;`  that you are using, you will have some issues with some of your images, as not all of your images are transparent to blend in with the background.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm not sure how to use this. I'm pasting my HTML into the Magento editor. This CSS does not work when doing that. I do want a white background but not sure how to do that.

Comment: @user1526396 you can add this in the file style.css which is located at http://petpresto.com.au/skin/frontend/shopper/default/css/styles.css .

Comment: Hmmm, doesnt seem to make any difference.

Comment: @user1526396 you still haven't made the changes to the css file to take effect. You will need to use an ftp program(like filezilla) if you don't have access to the server,in order to make changes to the css.

Comment: I made the changes but I deleted the changes after nothing happened. I will add them again and leave for you to see. I have tied with and without the commented line.

Comment: @user1526396 Your local.css at line 209 has some rules applying on the .std img which overwrites the changes you made. http://petpresto.com.au/skin/frontend/shopper/default/css/local.css . Can you disable these rules there and see if it helps you?

Comment: Doesnt seem to make much difference either. I think this is going to take too much time for what it is worth. I am going to get a designer to fomat the sales page into image blocks instead. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR TIME! I really do appreciate it. Its just taking up too much time for what it is worth. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

In your code where you have:

```
<table cellspacing="10" border="0" align="center" style="width: 600px;">
```

Change for:

```
<table cellspacing="10" border="0" align="center" style="width: 600px; float:none; margin: auto;">
```

That solves your problem. I'd recommend to create a class for the table tag and place this css in a file apart.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks! That solved the center align problem. How about the others? (white background, vertical align center, wrong size image on chrome, responsive)